# Chicken Scheme - Error: unbound variable: command-line-arguments

Tags: chicken-scheme

Chicken doesn't seem to recognize command-line-arguments. I've tried compiling the .scm and running `(display (command-line-arguments))` and it throws unbound variable every time. I've reinstalled from the Void Linux repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have found [the documentation for command-line-arguments](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Module%20(chicken%20process-context)#command-line-arguments) on the documentation for the module `(chicken process-context)`. These modules aren't loaded by default in CHICKEN 5, as opposed to CHICKEN 4 (where it was quite ill-defined what was loaded there by default).

In CHICKEN 5, as [is documented](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Modules#predefined-modules) in the manual page explaining about Modules, by default only `scheme`, `(chicken base)` and `(chicken syntax)` are available to a program. Anything else you will need to explicitly import.

So, long story short, your program needs a `(import (chicken process-context))` at the start, that should fix it!